# execl return - Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, exec

My question is: after finishing the execution of the new process image, the function

> execl()

would return the execution to the caller process or to the father process?

Comment: Neither; the parent process continues its merry way regardless of what the child does (unless the parent decides to wait for the child to die, for example).  The grandparent never knows about its grandchild.  The only time any of the `exec*()` functions returns is if it failed.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the execl function would return to the "father" process any time the function is called by the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using one of the `exec` family of functions, you **do not expect the function to return at all**. The program counter begins at the first instruction of the binary image that replaced the calling process.

From the Darwin man page:

> If any of the exec() functions returns, an error will have occurred. 
>   The return value is -1, and the global variable errno will be set to
>   indicate the error.

*There was a comment asking about the following, but it was deleted:*

If you are in a child process, and `execl` succeeds, then the child process is replaced by the new binary. If it fails, then control returns to that child process (the caller). There's no strict relationship between `fork` and `exec`, if that's what you're asking. If you are in a child process, and `exec` fails, then you have a "forked" child process, which is a copy of the original parent process. At this point you probably want to print some error message and exit from the child process.

If you want to know *why* it failed, you can use the following pattern:

```
if (execl(...)) {
    perror(NULL);
    exit(errno);
}
```

For example, try running this program, the error message will indicate how to fix the program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (const int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    if (execl("ls", "ls", "-la", NULL)) {
        perror(NULL);
        exit(errno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The solution, use `execlp` instead of `execl` in this case.

Comment: Yes I deleted it because I was writing a new one :) Thanks